# Why does TensorBoard embeddings need the events.out.tfevents.[...] file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, word-embedding

Why does TensorBoard embeddings need the events.out.tfevents.[...] file?

If I place the following files in a folder:

[image]

TensorBoard embeddings can view it:

[image]

If I remove `events.out.tfevents.1490126578.FRANCKY-PC` then TensorBoard embeddings cannot view it anymore. Why?